# How can I get the first and subsequent words out of underscore-separated names?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.6, special-characters

trying to get words among underscores

I have tried this implementing using python regular exps with sets, quantifiers and backreferencing in regex.

```
re.findall('(?:,?)(?: ?)(\w+)(?:_) ',text5)
```

```
text5 = 'aa_bb, aaa_ccc_ssdd, asd_qqsa, lkdd_trw_asdf_asdd'
```

I need the first words i.e;

```
['aa','aaa','asd','lkdd']
```

However, the result that i am getting is

```
['aa', 'aaa_ccc', 'asd', 'lkdd_trw_asdf']
```

Please help in getting other words as well, such as for the second word, the output should be

```
['bb','ccc','qqsa','trw']
```

likewise, for 3rd word o/p be

```
['ssdd','asdf']
```

4th word

```
['asdd']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to obtain the first words before the underscore:

```
import re

text5 = 'aa_bb, aaa_ccc_ssdd, asd_qqsa, lkdd_trw_asdf_asdd'

split_text5 = text5.split()

first_Words = []

for string in split_text5:
    re1 = re.search(r'[^_]*', string)
    re2 = re1.group(0)
    first_Words.append(re2)

print(first_Words)
```

To obtain all the words:

```
import re

text5 = 'aa_bb, aaa_ccc_ssdd, asd_qqsa, lkdd_trw_asdf_asdd'

split_text5 = text5.split()

all_Words = []

for string in split_text5:
    re3 = re.findall(r'[^_]*', string)
    all_Words.extend(re3)

clean_list = []
for word in all_Words:
    if word not in '':
        clean_list.append(word)

all_Words = clean_list

print(all_Words)
```

The above code will retain commas in a string. If you do Not want to include commas, then use:

```
re3 = re.findall(r'[^_,]*', string)
```

To obtain first_Words, second_Words, third_Words, then fourth_Words:

```
import re

text5 = 'aa_bb, aaa_ccc_ssdd, asd_qqsa, lkdd_trw_asdf_asdd'

split_text5 = text5.split()

all_Words = []

for string in split_text5:
    re3 = re.findall(r'[^_,]*', string)
    all_Words.append(re3)

#print(all_Words)

clean_list0 = []

clean_list1 = []

clean_list2 = []

clean_list3 = []

for word in all_Words[0]:
    if word not in '':
        clean_list0.append(word)

for word in all_Words[1]:
    if word not in '':
        clean_list1.append(word)

for word in all_Words[2]:
    if word not in '':
        clean_list2.append(word)

for word in all_Words[3]:
    if word not in '':
        clean_list3.append(word)

all_Words = [clean_list0, clean_list1, clean_list2, clean_list3] 


first_Words = []
try:
    first_Words.append(clean_list0[0])
except IndexError:
    pass
try:
    first_Words.append(clean_list1[0])
except IndexError:
    pass
try:
    first_Words.append(clean_list2[0])
except IndexError:
    pass
try:
    first_Words.append(clean_list3[0])
except IndexError:
    pass
print(first_Words)

second_Words = []
try:
    second_Words.append(clean_list0[1])
except IndexError:
    pass
try:
    second_Words.append(clean_list1[1])
except IndexError:
    pass
try:
    second_Words.append(clean_list2[1])
except IndexError:
    pass
try:
    second_Words.append(clean_list3[1])
except IndexError:
    pass
print(second_Words)

third_Words = []
try:
    third_Words.append(clean_list0[2]) 
except IndexError:
    pass
try:
    third_Words.append(clean_list1[2])
except IndexError:
    pass
try:
    third_Words.append(clean_list2[2])
except IndexError:
    pass
try:
    third_Words.append(clean_list3[2])
except IndexError:
    pass
print(third_Words)

fourth_Words = []
try:
    fourth_Words.append(clean_list0[3])
except IndexError:
    pass
try:
    fourth_Words.append(clean_list1[3])
except IndexError:
    pass
try:
    fourth_Words.append(clean_list2[3])
except IndexError:
    pass
try:
    fourth_Words.append(clean_list3[3])
except IndexError:
    pass
print(fourth_Words)
```

Comment: Thanks, Mate! worked to extract the first word and all words. How about taking the 2nd, 3rd and 4th word only, if exists?

Comment: Please see the additional code in my answer for taking the 2nd, 3rd and 4th word only, if it exists.